# GLSurfaceView is too slow when rendering effects

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, opengl-es, rendering

I am trying to do add filtering on image , I used `GLSurfaceView` 
to show effects changing on run-time but it to slow when rendering between effects, what could be the problem ?

here is my code ...

```
public class EffictActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    private RecyclerView recList;
    int mCurrentEffect;
    private GLSurfaceView mEffectView;
    private int[] mTextures = new int[2];
    private EffectContext mEffectContext;
    private Effect mEffect;
    Bitmap bm;
    private TextureRenderer mTexRenderer = new TextureRenderer();
    private int mImageWidth;
    EGL10 egl;
    private int mImageHeight;
    Button saveImage;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    private volatile boolean saveFrame;
    ProgressDialog mDialog;
    public void setCurrentEffect(int effect) {
        mCurrentEffect = effect;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_effict);
        saveImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.effectSave) ;
        mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
        mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mEffectView.setRenderer(this);
        mEffectView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mCurrentEffect = 0;
        mDialog = Utils.SetProgressBar(mDialog, this);
         new CountDownTimer(3000 ,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

        recList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rc_filter);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        FilterAdapterFactory filterAdapter = new FilterAdapterFactory(this);
        recList.setAdapter(filterAdapter);

        recList.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                setCurrentEffect(position);
                mEffectView.requestRender();
            }
        }));
        saveImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                    mInterstitialAd.show();
//                }
                SaveImage(bm);

            }

        });

    }
    private void loadTextures() {
        // Generate textures
        GLES20.glGenTextures(2, mTextures, 0);
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root + "/HijabPhoto/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("path"));
        mImageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mImageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mTexRenderer.updateTextureSize(mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
        // Upload to texture
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextures[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        // Set texture parameters
        GLToolbox.initTexParams();
        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    private void initEffect() {
        EffectFactory effectFactory = mEffectContext.getFactory();
        if (mEffect != null) {
            mEffect.release();
        }
        /**
         * Initialize the correct effect based on the selected menu/action item
         */
        switch (mCurrentEffect) {

            case 0:
                break;

            case 1:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_AUTOFIX);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", 0.5f);
                break;

            case 2:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BLACKWHITE);
                mEffect.setParameter("black", .1f);
                mEffect.setParameter("white", .7f);
                break;

            case 3:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_BRIGHTNESS);
                mEffect.setParameter("brightness", 2.0f);
                break;

            case 4:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CONTRAST);
                mEffect.setParameter("contrast", 1.4f);
                break;

            case 5:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_CROSSPROCESS);
                break;

            case 6:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DOCUMENTARY);
                break;

            case 7:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_DUOTONE);
                mEffect.setParameter("first_color", Color.YELLOW);
                mEffect.setParameter("second_color", Color.DKGRAY);
                break;

            case 8:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FILLLIGHT);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", .8f);
                break;

            case 9:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FISHEYE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case 10:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("vertical", true);
                break;

            case 11:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_FLIP);
                mEffect.setParameter("horizontal", true);
                break;

            case 12:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAIN);
                mEffect.setParameter("strength", 1.0f);
                break;

            case 13:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_GRAYSCALE);
                break;

            case 14:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_LOMOISH);
                break;

            case 15:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
                break;

            case 16:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_POSTERIZE);
                break;

            case 17:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_ROTATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("angle", 180);
                break;

            case 18:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SATURATE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            case 19:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SEPIA);
                break;

            case 20:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_SHARPEN);
                break;

            case 21:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TEMPERATURE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .9f);
                break;

            case 22:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_TINT);
                mEffect.setParameter("tint", Color.MAGENTA);
                break;

            case 23:
                mEffect = effectFactory.createEffect(EffectFactory.EFFECT_VIGNETTE);
                mEffect.setParameter("scale", .5f);
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }

    private void applyEffect() {
        mEffect.apply(mTextures[0], mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mTextures[1]);
    }

    private void renderResult() {
        if (mCurrentEffect != 0) {
            // if no effect is chosen, just render the original bitmap
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[1]);
        } else {
            saveFrame=true;
            // render the result of applyEffect()
            mTexRenderer.renderTexture(mTextures[0]);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (mTexRenderer != null) {
            mTexRenderer.updateViewSize(width, height);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        egl = (EGL10) EGLContext.getEGL();
        gl = (GL10)egl.eglGetCurrentContext().getGL();
        if (!mInitialized) {
            // Only need to do this once
            mEffectContext = EffectContext.createWithCurrentGlContext();
            mTexRenderer.init();
            loadTextures();
            mInitialized = true;
        }
        if (mCurrentEffect != 0) {
            // if an effect is chosen initialize it and apply it to the texture
            initEffect();
            applyEffect();
        }
        renderResult();
         bm = createBitmapFromGLSurface(0 ,0, mImageWidth , mImageHeight , gl);
        SaveImage(bm);
    }



    private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/HijabPhoto");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        File file = new File(myDir, fileName);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            Toast.makeText(EffictActivity.this, getString(R.string.imageSavedSuccrss), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.w("FILE PATH===", file.getPath().toString());
            String path = file.getPath().toString();
            addImageToGallery(path, EffictActivity.this);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
//            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                mInterstitialAd.show();
//            }
            Intent sharin = new Intent(EffictActivity.this,ShareActivity.class);
            sharin.putExtra("path",fileName);
            Log.w("file path",""+file.getPath().toString());
            startActivity(sharin);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
        context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    private Bitmap createBitmapFromGLSurface(int x, int y, int w, int h, GL10 gl)
            throws OutOfMemoryError {
        int bitmapBuffer[] = new int[w * h];
        int bitmapSource[] = new int[w * h];
        IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(bitmapBuffer);
        intBuffer.position(0);

        try {
            gl.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);
            int offset1, offset2;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
                offset1 = i * w;
                offset2 = (h - i - 1) * w;
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                    int texturePixel = bitmapBuffer[offset1 + j];
                    int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                    int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                    int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;
                    bitmapSource[offset2 + j] = pixel;
                }
            }
        } catch (GLException e) {
            return null;
        }

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSource, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }


}
```

any help please...

Comment: Your onSurfaceCreated() method is empty and all your work is in the onDrawFrame() method. The best option would be to glReadPixels() and then send the data to another thread to handle away from the GL thread.

Comment: would you please explain how to do that in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much slow memory and even external storage access done in the onDrawFrame method.

- You are creating a shader and a texture (that's the least of the problem)
- You are creating a new bitmap each time where you copy your data into
- And then, the slowest part, you are even saving it into the external directory.

These are the problems.

Comment: I tried to find a way to save texture , somewhere else then onDrawFrame but i don't find any , would you please explain how to solve it ?

Comment: I solve it I remove the function savePhoto from onDrawFrame thank you :)